How to get terminal background color in Jansi?
Could anyone say how to get terminal background color using Jansi, if it is possible. I need it because it is difficult/impossible to provide good contrast if you don't know background color.
Could anyone say how to do it?

You’re quite right that it’s important to pick a foreground color with good contrast.  I don’t think there is a way to query the current background, so I expect you will have to make sure you always set the background in addition to setting the foreground.
